# Convert getdate() to int

Tags: sql, casting, int, getdate

When I run the following query:

```
select convert(int, getdate())
```

I get the result:

```
-----------
41238

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Does anyone knows what does this mean?

Comment: Allright! Found the answer already. It's the days.


`SELECT dateadd(day, convert(int, getdate()), '01/01/1900')`

Comment: No it means the days since 1/1/1900.

Comment: Yep! But it depends on what DBMS you're using, right? Or all of them start counting at 1/1/1900?

Comment: Depends, they could be but not likely.  Ask us what you are really looking for and we can provide a solution, or are you just playing with `convert()`?

Comment: Actually I was searching how to convert int to datetime. One thing led to another...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its the number of days since I think `1/1/1900`, sql-server keeps the number of days since then.

Try dividing that number by roughly 365.
You should get the value back in years (112).
Since 1900 + 112 = 2012

Answer (score 2):

This is because SQL natively keeps the number of days since `01/01/1900`

The decimal after the integer value is the time.

`32.5` would equal `02/01/1900 12:00 pm`

If you are looking to get and work with only part of the date as an integer I would recommend using [datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

This statement would return only the month and convert that value to an integer.

```
select convert(int, datepart(mm,getdate())
```