# How to Convert Sysdate to Int?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to Extract Month and year from SYSDATETIME :

Pass from "2019-04-26 12:13:52.1683125" TO "201904"

Then Convert "201904" to INT.

Comment: Please provide evidence of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert getdate() to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571054/convert-getdate-to-int)

Comment: how  is date represented as 201904??

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER. The date 201904 (YYYYMM) is what i want to have. i want to convert the current date of my system to YYYYMM then convert this to int. So i could compare it to a date that i  have in my Database in this format

Comment: 201904 is not a valid date. Are you storing those values in a char/varchar column?

Comment: `SYSDATE` doesn't exist in SQL Server. There is `SYSDATETIME()`, however, that returns a `datetime2(7)`, not a `(var)char(6)`. Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? As mentioned above, `201904` is not a `date`. That is either a integer or a `(var)char` value. A `date`, in SQL Server, holds data for the year, month **and** day.

Comment: I am sorry it is SYSDATETIME(). I want to get the month and the year from the SYSDATETIME() and this result to convert it to INT so i can compare it to   variables stored as  INT

Comment: Fix your schema and do not store dates as strings or integers but use some date/time type. Then they're comparable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL server as Database then below script should work for you

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS VARCHAR)+ RIGHT('00'+CAST(MONTH(getdate()) AS VARCHAR),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a numeric representation of the date as YYYYMM in SQL Server, I would recommend:

```
select year(getdate()) * 100 + month(getdate())
```

You can use `sysdatetime()` if you prefer.